# "As of now" construction

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

Does the construction "as of now on" mean "from here on"?

- As of now you'll be doing your homework right after school.

Comment: "As of now on" is not natural English.  "From now on" (or possibly "as of now") is the idiom .  Can you post a link to where you found this example?

Comment: I might have overheard "on". I heard it in a TV series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as of now on** is not idiomatic at all: the **on** is superfluous. If you look at this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20of%20now%20on%2Cas%20of%20now%2C%20from%20now%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20of%20now%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20of%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20now%20on%3B%2Cc0), you will see that its usage is practically zero and  **as of now** is negligible compared to **from now on**. I suggest that you say

> From now on, you'll be doing your homework right after school.

Comment: I disagree, I think these phrases imply something different; '*from now on*' implies that you are going to do something *that excludes the current action*, while '*as of now*' is more *inclusive*. [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/as%20of%20now) does not list '*from now on*' as a synonym, although [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/as-of-now) does.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey, if you were talking about 'as of this year/ from this year on' I might accept that the difference is significant, but 'as of now/from now on'??? **Now** is a very fine hair to split. Anyway, Cambridge Dictionary thinks they are the same. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/now?q=from+now+on

Comment: I'll meet you on *fine hair to split* :)